# JS.Canvas. Непонятные пиксели(тени) при рендеринге прямоугольника и круга

Tags: javascript, canvas

При выставлении ширины линии в 1(ctx.lineWidth = 1), получается такая картина [видео](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1HhXIKjXDSltkvERPSilTGJFfZSD3ibGj)

Линия сама толще чем задана. Цвет при отрисовке почему-то прозрачный и с каждым нарисованой фигурой, прозрачность уменьшается и только на 5 прямоугольнике прозрачность исчезает. У круга закрашиваются дополнительные пиксели, прозрачным цветом. Как-будто тени, но это не тени т.к. уже приписывал их отключение.

Но если задать ctx.lineWidth = 2, то проблема с прямоугольником исчезает и всё рендерится как надо, но с кругом проблема так и остаётся.

Координаты все целочисленные т.е. x = 5, а не x = 5.3467, что могло давать бы подобную картину. При рисовании карандашом в начале видео видно, что проблема не в этом.

````
function rectangle() {
  let x0, y0, x1, y1;
  let mouseDown;

  data.canv.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
    if (data.tools.isRectangle === true) {
      mouseDown = true;

      //data.ctx.lineWidth = data.pixelSize;
      data.ctx.lineWidth = 1
      data.ctx.strokeStyle = data.colors.currentColor;
      //data.currentCtx.lineWidth = data.pixelSize;
      data.currentCtx.lineWidth = 1
      data.currentCtx.strokeStyle = data.colors.currentColor;

      x0 = Math.floor(e.offsetX / data.canvIndex);
      y0 = Math.floor(e.offsetY / data.canvIndex);
    }

    data.canv.addEventListener('mousemove', function mouseMove(e) {
      if (mouseDown === true) {
        data.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, data.canv.width, data.canv.height);

        x1 = Math.floor(e.offsetX / data.canvIndex);
        y1 = Math.floor(e.offsetY / data.canvIndex);

        data.ctx.strokeRect(x0, y0, x1 - x0, y1 - y0);
      }
    })

    data.canv.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
      mouseDown = false;

      if (data.tools.isRectangle === true) {
        data.currentCtx.strokeRect(x0, y0, x1 - x0, y1 - y0);   

        data.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, data.canv.width, data.canv.height);
      }
    })
  })
}```
````

Comment: канва растянута css ом?

Comment: canvas-у задана width: 100%, находиться в контейнере, которому уже я задаю уже размеры через js в px. Попробовал сейчас задавать канвасу размер через HTML и через js непосредственно самому канвасу, а не его контейнеру, не помогло.

Comment: а как Вы устанавливаете размер?

Comment: HTML: canvas-base > canvas-wrapper > canvas

Comment: //вычисление  размеров пикселя канваса
  canvasPixelWidth = Math.floor((canvasBase.offsetWidth * 0.99) / canvasLayer_1.width);

Comment: //задание ширины контейнера канваса
  canvasWrapper.style.width = `${canvasLayer_1.width * canvasPixelWidth}px`;

Comment: //вычисление  и задание количества пикселей канваса, которые смогут поместиться при текущей высотке canvasBase
  canvasLayer_1.height =  Math.floor(canvasBase.offsetHeight * 0.99 / canvasPixelWidth);

Comment: // высотa контейнера канваса
  canvasWrapper.style.height = `${canvasLayer_1.height * canvasPixelWidth}px`;

Comment: В общих чертах, делаю так чтобы размер пикселя канваса равнялся целочисленному количеству пикселей  т.е. 1px  равнялся допустим 4px, а не 4.5px.

Comment: После вашего ответа попробовал применить эту формулу ``canvasWrapper.style.width = `${canvasLayer_1.width * canvasPixelWidth}px` ``, но уже не к контейнеру, а к самому холсту ``canvas1.style.width = `${canvasLayer_1.width * canvasPixelWidth}px` ``. Эффекта никакого.

Comment: размер канвы устанавливается через атрибуты width и height, растягивание css ом не меняет размер изображения, оно всего лишь растягивается

Comment: Значит расстягивать канвас в корне не верно.Хотя на курсах в RSSchool так делал весь поток насколько знаю и все неправильно получается. Спасибо, буду переписывать алгоритмы)

Comment: Набросал на кодопен codepen.io/andreykokorev/pen/RwPKjWw. Если увеличить на максимум, то будет видно те же самые проблемы: грани прямоугольника прозрачные, шире заданных и прозрачные пиксели у круга. Задав ширину лини в 2, толщина граней также не увеличивается,а просто они теряют прозрачность. Получается проблема не в css, что в принципе и логично, css просто расстягивает и эту проблему сразу видно.